# An argument definition must end with a newline

Tags: terraform

I have a dynamic block in aws_cloudfront_distribution which is the following:

```
  dynamic "ordered_cache_behavior" {
for_each = var.ordered_cache_behaviors
content {
  path_pattern              = ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern
  allowed_methods           = ordered_cache_behavior.value.allowed_methods
  cached_methods            = ordered_cache_behavior.value.cached_methods
  target_origin_id          = var.origin_id
  cache_policy_id           = var.cache_policy_ids["${var.policy_prefix}${ordered_cache_behavior.value.cache_policy_name}"]
  origin_request_policy_id  = ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern = "/" ? var.origin_request_policy_ids["whitelist_policy"] : null
  dynamic "lambda_function_association" {
    for_each = var.enable_auth ? var.default_cache_behavior.lambda_function_association : ordered_cache_behavior.value.lambda_function_association
    content {
      event_type   = lambda_function_association.value.event_type
      include_body = lambda_function_association.value.include_body
      lambda_arn   = lambda_function_association.value.lambda_arn != "" ? lambda_function_association.value.lambda_arn : local.lambda_mapping[lambda_function_association.value.event_type]
    }
  }
  compress               = ordered_cache_behavior.value.compress
  viewer_protocol_policy = ordered_cache_behavior.value.viewer_protocol_policy
}
```

I got :

```
    │ Error: Missing newline after argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 111, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "web_distribution":
│  111:       origin_request_policy_id  = ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern = "/" ? var.origin_request_policy_ids["origin_1H_1D_plp_pdp_whitelist_whitelist_none"] : null
│ 
│ An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

I still dont know why I am getting the error, so what I basically wanna do is to define origin_request_policy_id based on if path pattern is / .
am I missing something?

Comment: This `ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern = "/"` should be `ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern == "/"`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didnt pay attention. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Terraform's parser is rejecting what you wrote here because you used the `=` symbol in the middle of an expression. Terraform doesn't understand what you intended and so it's guessing that the expression ends after `ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern` and then complaining that there isn't a newline at that point.

However, I think what you really intended to do here was test for equality between `ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern` and `"/"`. The operator for equality test is `==` rather than `=`, so you can add the extra equals character to make this valid:

```
  origin_request_policy_id  = ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern == "/" ? var.origin_request_policy_ids["whitelist_policy"] : null
```

Because this expression is long and has multiple complex parts, I might suggest rewriting it to be a multi-line expression like this for readability, but of course that's subjective and optional:

```
  origin_request_policy_id = (
    ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern == "/" ?
    var.origin_request_policy_ids["whitelist_policy"] :
    null
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't assign something in an definition in the same line.

```
 origin_request_policy_id  = ordered_cache_behavior.value.path_pattern = "/"...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).